# Blocked autofocusing on a form control in a cross-origin subframe

Tags: security, iframe, cross-domain

Using Chrome, when I'm trying to change values of an input located in an IFrame of another app on our server, I get an error in Chrome:

> "Blocked autofocusing on a form control in a cross-origin subframe."

On production (when the two apps are hosted on the same domain) it's working, but on localhost development I can't make it to work.

I've already tried starting Chrome with the following:

- --disable-web-security
- --ignore-certificate-errors
- --disable-site-isolation-trials
- --allow-external-pages
- --disable-site-isolation-for-policy

but none worked.

Has anyone has an idea how to make it work?
If any change on server side needed, it's also an option.

Comment: Have you tried adding any of the iframe's sandbox param? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

Answer (score 6):

For me the issue was a chrome extension ( Dashlane ). I disabled it on that site an it worked. I don't know if this helps you in any way but I had the same issue and this worked for me.

edit: I also had the issue on localhost however haven't tried it yet on server.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to chrome://flags
2. Disable SameSite by default cookies
3. Relaunch chrome

[image]